# Rank of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

If A is an $(m *  k)$ - matrix and B is a $(k * n)$ - matrix, how would I show that $rnk(AB) ≤ rnk(B)$? I'm confused as to what conditions on matrix A would ensure that this equality holds. What would they be?

Comment: This question has been answered here recently, and the idea is that you show $\text{ null(B)} \subseteq \text{null(AB)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B.$  that means the row space of $AB$ is contained within the row space of $B.$ therefore the rank of $AB$ which is the dimension of the row space is less or equal to the rank of $B.$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Are there any conditions on $A$ that would make the expression untrue?

Comment: none. that $ranl(AB) \le rank(B)$ no matter what $A$ is. $A$ can range from near identity(if $A$ is reactangular) to zero matrix.

Answer (score 2):

$$
Bx = 0 \Rightarrow (AB) x = A(Bx) = A0 = 0
$$
This means
$$
\mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } B \le \mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } AB
$$
The rank nullity theorem gives:
\begin{align}
\mbox{rk }AB &= n -\mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } AB \\
\mbox{rk } B &= n -\mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } B
\end{align}

This gives
$$
\mbox{rk } AB = \mbox{rk } B + 
\mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } B  - \mbox{dim } \mbox{ker } AB 
\le \mbox{rk } B
$$